# Snakemake expand on a dictionary, keeping wildcards

Tags: python, snakemake

I have a dictionary like the following:

```py
data = {
    "group1": ["a", "b", "c"], 
    "group2": ["x", "y", "z"]
}
```

**I want to use expand to get all combinations between the keys and their values separately** in "rule all", s.t. the expected output files are e.g. "group1/a.txt", "group1/b.txt", ... "group2/x.txt, "group2/y.txt" ...

```
rule all: 
    input: 
        expand("{group}/{sub_group}.txt", group = ???, sub_group = ???)
```

I need this for the rule "some_rule":

```py
rule some_rule: 
    input: "single_input_file.txt"
    output: "{group}/{sub_group}.txt"
    params: 
        group=group, # how do I extract these placeholders?
        sub_group=sub_group
    script: 
        "some_script.R"
```

The reason why I need to have `group` and `sub_group` wildcards is because I need to pass them to the `params` of rule "some_rule"

I tried to hardcode all output files needed in the "rule all" with list comprehension, but then the placeholders are not defined in the wildcards and I cannot pass them to the params.

So I guess I need to define the "rule all" input files using `expand`, but here I don't know how to get the correct files, as **I need the combinations to be performed individually between "group1" and its values and "group2" and its values.**

I also cannot use an input function for the rule "some_rule", as it has only one singular static input file.

In other similar questions on StackOverflow, either there is not the combinatorial problem, or they create the input files for "rule_all" using plain python, which makes me loose the wildcards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem using a **custom combinator function**.

```
def pairwise_product(*args):
result = []
for group, sub_group in zip(*args):
    sub_group = ([sub_group[0]], sub_group[1])
    for sub_sub_group in itertools.product(*sub_group):
        result.append((group, sub_sub_group))
return result
```

Looking at the source code for [snakemake's expand function](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/blob/3326a6f7bbaf9c277400625649c3da903e251e2f/snakemake/io.py#L1194), I realized that I can use my own combinator function.

`pairwise_product` expects as input two lists of tuples, where each tuple contains the wildcard name and the wildcard value, e.g.

```
wildcard1 = [("group", "group1"), ("group", "group2")]
wildcard2 = [("sub_group", ["a", "b", "c"]), ("sub_group", ["x", "y", "z"])]
pairwise_product(wildcard1, wildcard2)
```

The output of this function call would be:

```
[(('group', 'group1'), ('sub_group', 'a')),
 (('group', 'group1'), ('sub_group', 'b')),
 (('group', 'group1'), ('sub_group', 'c')),
 (('group', 'group2'), ('sub_group', 'x')),
 (('group', 'group2'), ('sub_group', 'y')),
 (('group', 'group2'), ('sub_group', 'z'))]
```

And the output of the **expand function** would be:

```
expand("{group}/{sub_group}.txt", pairwise_product, group=data.keys(), sub_group=data.values())

['group1/a.txt',
 'group1/b.txt',
 'group1/c.txt',
 'group2/x.txt',
 'group2/y.txt',
 'group2/z.txt']
```

With this solution I also get the wildcards I want, i.e. the individual elements in the list-values for each dictionary key separately.

Note that this function has been designed for only two wildcards in the format as shown above in the `data` dictionary and not tested for other formats.

Answer (score 2):

Answer based on your comment.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "group1": ["a", "b", "c"],
    "group2": ["x", "y", "z"]
}

df = pd.DataFrame([(k, v) for k, vs in data.items() for v in vs],
                  columns=['Group', 'Value'])

rule all:
    input:
        expand("{group}/{sub_group}.txt", zip, group=df['Group'], sub_group=df['Value'])

rule some_rule:
    output: "{group}/{sub_group}.txt"
    params:
        group='{group}',
        sub_group='{sub_group}'
    shell:
        """
        echo {params.group} {params.sub_group} > {output}
        """
```

Comment: Nice solution, might be even more straightforward than mine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
rule some_rule: 
    input: "single_input_file.txt"
    output: "{group}/{sub_group}.txt"
    script: 
        "some_script.R"
```

and access the value of the wildcards `{group}` and `{subgroups}` inside the R
script with e.g. `snakemake@wildcards[['group']]` (not tested but I think it
should do it).

Alternatively I think you could have:

```
params:
    group='{group}'
    sub_group='{sub_group}',
```

Answer (score 0):

#### You can use nested list comprehensions

```
data = {
    "group1": ["a", "b", "c"], 
    "group2": ["x", "y", "z"]
}

files = sum(
    [
        [f"{key}/{value}.txt" for value in values] for key,values in data.items()],
    []
)

print(files)
```

I think you are planning to then run a program on each of the files? If so:

```
for file in files:
     # run script on `file`
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am not sure how I can use this in a snakemake pipeline. I tried to construct the output files with a list comprehension before, but then I can't access the {group} and {sub_group} wildcards anymore in "some_rule".